# tableview's Datasource array's value is automatically changes to 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

```
 var noteList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() // declaration of `noteObjects`


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {


            let temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray!



            self.noteList = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray


            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {
            print(error!.userInfo)

        }
    }
    //populating noteObjects
```

i have a tableView who's datasource is an Array 'noteObjects' its  type is NSMutableArray  , so the problem is that every time i open my tableView my 'noteObjects' array's Value is 0 but then it automatically changes to desired value , how can i say this ? i did this in different stages of my tableViewController  -

i printed the `noteObjects.count` in `ViewDidload`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()


    print("\(noteObjects.count) viewDidlaod3") }
```

output :

```
0 viewDidlaod3
```

inside `cellForRowAtindexPath` i printed this

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  print("\(noteObjects.count) in cellForAtIndexPath")       
return cell }
```

output : 
`18 in cellForAtIndexPath`

and if i move to another View then again open this tableView it keeps giving the sae result , (note object.count = 0 at first)

i want to use that noteObjects.count so that i can confirm that if the tableView's datasource is empty so i can show a message , but when am using this then its always showing that my tableview is empty because at first noteObjects.count is 0

if  details provided above is not enough then please let me know i'll fix it

Comment: Where is set `noteObjects`?

Comment: Explain where / how you are setting up noteObjects?

Comment: @Larme just Updated my question

Comment: @DogCoffee hey just updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a if statement after the synchronisation method

```
  if noteObjects.count < 1 {

    let Alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Data to Display", message: "ther's nothing bro you should pull to refresh", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OKAY Got IT")
    Alert.show()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The api call 'findeObjectsInBackground' is asynchronous meaning the closure is executed later in time when result is obtained in a different thread. So getting back to the main thread and reloading the table view when data is ready will solve the problem. You can read more about these type of closures as they are very common in iOS.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            let temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray!
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                 self.noteList = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        } 
        else {
            print(error!.userInfo)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just moved my code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and it worked For me

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)



        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()

    print("\(noteObjects.count) view appears")



    if noteObjects.count < 1 {

        let Alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Data to Display", message: "ther's nothing bro you should pull to refresh", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OKAY Got IT")
        Alert.show()

    }
    }
```

now noteObject.count is getting  check after updating its Value

Comment: Better to fetch your data in `viewDidLoad` method. As said in @Lukas answer, your problem is caused by the asynchronous behavior. Your current approach will still alert the user even if there is something in your data source, because the count is checked and the alert is fired immediately after your query, You can try to put the count check within your query block.